# Split the Data with comma (,) seperation and displaying it accordingly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, split

Here is my Controller's return in case of error

```
return "0".",".$messages = $validator->messages();
```

So the ouput will be

```
0,{"firstname":["The firstname field is required."]"lastname":["The lastname field is required."]}
```

And splitting with ,

```
var dat = data.split(",");
if(dat[0] == "0")
 {
  $('#stage').html(dat[1]);
 }
```

So, if i have a first error the output will be

```
{"firstname":["The firstname field is required."]
```

How can i make splitting or handle it to make display only the errors

i.e.,The firstname field is required.

Update :

As Codebird suggests :

return $validator->messages();

```
if(data != '')
 {
   obj=JSON.parse(data);
   var error_string='';
   $.each(obj, function(entry) {
      error_string+=obj[entry]+'<br />';
   });
   $('#stage').html(error_string);
 } else {
   $('#stage').html('Success Saving');
 }
```

Console :

[image]

Comment: why dont you just use JSON?

Comment: Because i have to check the conditin whether if dat[0]=="0" or dat[0]==1 for success and failure condition

Comment: split on comma you get the first number, then if it is 0, replace `0,` in your original string, then treat the remaining part as JSON to display the errors. In all cases it is the part after the `0,` that is JSON. At your place I won't return 0 or 1. In case of error I would return the error string, in case of success I would return an empty message. This way I test the message if it is empty, then success, else JSON and display.

Comment: @CodeBird I don't think that is valid JSON, even after the `0,`

Comment: It is, he just forgot the commas.

Comment: @Flosculus if you notice in his question he shows that dat[1] is `{"firstname":["The firstname field is required."]` so basically this means that javascript split that string on commas too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, I would have handled this, this way:

first thing, you have to json_encode the `$validator->messages()` as it is an array, so your php becomes like this:

The return

```
 return json_encode($validator->messages());
```

then the JS:

```
 if(data != '')
 {
   obj=JSON.parse(data);
   var error_string='';
   $.each(obj, function(entry) {
      error_string+=obj[entry]+'<br />';
   });
   $('#stage').html(error_string);
 } else {
    //Success goes here.
 }
```

Comment: obj=JSON.parse(data); is that correct, bcoz i am getting uncaught exception here

Comment: what's the uncaught exception? what's exactly the error @CiiLearner

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: And if i put the code inside my function(data) i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: @CiiLearner update your question with all the javascript code pls

Comment: @CiiLearner `console.log(data)` before the `if(data!=...` show us what you see in the console pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64304/discussion-between-cii-learner-and-codebird).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
// php - I assume $validator->messages() returns json
$response = array(
    'messages' => json_decode($validator->messages()),
    'success'  => false,
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

and

```
// javascript
if (!data['success']) {
     $.each(data['messages'], function(index, value) {
         $('#stage').append(value + '<br/>');
     });
}
```

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzf5tuuc/

Comment: In the javascript code you given, its throwing uncaught exception error in the console